# PHP Uploading a Large image and resizing with proportion like Photoshop

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, photoshop, image-resizing

A quick brief. We currently have to make small, medium and large images based on product images we have on our site. Not being a wiz on PHP I thought I would still try to automate this nightmare.

The image we upload and dimension of the thumb is below

```
800 width x 1400 width LARGE
300 width x 525 width  THUMB
```

The problem with my PHP script is that it just resizes with scaling to proportion. I want to it to be able to scale down like in Photoshop, you just click shift and the image scales. I am trying to use `imagecopyresized` but with little luck.

```
<?php
// PHP UPLOAD SCRIPT

// VALIDATION OF FORM

if($_FILES['user_image']['type'] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES['user_image']['size'] < 3000000)
{
    // VARS
    $target_folder = 'images/'; 
    $upload_image = $target_folder.basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']); 

    // UPLOAD FUNCTION
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $upload_image)) 
    {

        // VARS FOR FILE NAMES
        $thumbnail = $target_folder."medium_x.jpg";
        $actual = $target_folder."large_x.jpg";

      // THUMBNAIL SIZE
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
        $newwidth = "300"; 
        $newheight = "525";

        // VARS FOR CALL BACK
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);

        // RESIZE WITH PROPORTION LIKE PHOTOSHOP HOLDING SHIFT
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        // MAKE NEW FILES
        imagejpeg($thumb, $thumbnail, 100);

        // FILE RENAMES
        rename($upload_image, $actual);

        {

            // SUCCESS MESSAGES
            ?>

            <p>
                Image Successfully uploaded!<br />
                Actual image: <?=$actual;?><br />
                Thumbnail image: <?=$thumbnail;?><br />

                <h1>Large</h1>
                <img src="<?=$actual;?>"/><br /><br />
                <h1>Medium</h1>
                <img src="<?=$thumbnail;?>"/><br /><br />
            </p>

            <?
        }
        // FAILED MESSAGES
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Upload failed.';
    }
}
else
{
        // NOT A JPEG
        echo 'Not a JPEG';
}

// END OF SCRIPT
?>
```

How can I resize properly without having a stretched image? Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this without buckets of PHP code is with Image Magick. See examples and sample command line here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill

(can call from PHP using exec() or similar)

**Edit:** Implementation as follows:

```
if($_FILES['user_image']['type'] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES['user_image']['size'] < 3000000)
{
    // VARS
    $target_folder = 'images/'; 
    $upload_image = $target_folder.basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);

    $thumbnail = $target_folder."medium_x.jpg";
    $actual = $target_folder."large_x.jpg";

    $newwidth = "300"; 
    $newheight = "525";

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $upload_image)) 
    {
        exec('convert '.$upload_image.' -resize '.$newwidth.'x'.$newheight.'^ '.$thumbnail);
        rename($upload_image, $actual);
    }
}
...
etc
```

You could optimise the way you handle the upload but I didn't want too totally change the structure of your code as I don't know what surrounds it. But basically, you push the image to ImageMagick's `convert`, and it will work it's magic.

If you want to crop as well as scale, the exec command would be:

`exec('convert '.$upload_image.' -resize '.$newwidth.'x'.$newheight.'^ -gravity center -extent '.$newwidth.'x'.$newheight.' '.$thumbnail);`

Comment: How could I integrate the command line feature within my script. Are you saying replace the `imagecopyresized` command with the references in the link above?

Comment: No need to execute command line commands to use this. Imagick already comes wrapped up in a nice php library

Comment: Command line is quicker and better documented. I don't see the point in adding the PHP overhead when a simple exec() can do all the hard work?

Comment: Love this very simple option without cluttering my PHP code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code snippet. Does what you need. Basically used to maintain ratio when creating the thumb.
http://snipplr.com/view/753/

Comment: Sorry but how would I implement this?